# how do I save STL map to file C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, fstream

I am trying to safe data to file using map, but I don't know how.
I want to save the student's name and age into the file and then when I look up a name            of a student it should display their age.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class student {
private:
    map<int, string> map;
public:
    void students(string name, int age);
};

void students(string name, int age) {
    if (age < 1) {
        cout << "You must enter a positive number." << endl;
        return;
    }
}

void main() {
    ofstream filemap;
    filemap.open("map.txt");
    int age;
    string name;
    cout << "Please enter the name : " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Please enter the age : " << endl;
    cin >> age;

// code to save map to file 

    filemap.close();
}
```

Comment: If this is a place to use a map (and I don't think that it is), surely it should be `map<string,int>`, and not `map<int,string>`.  Names are much more unique than ages, generally.

Comment: Thank you. I meant to type it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Start by deciding on exactly how the data will be stored in the file at the byte level. For example, it could be:

1. Each student occupies exactly one line in the file.
2. Lines are separated by a single newline character.
3. Each line consists of a quote, the student's name, a quote, a comma, and the student's age.

You then need to write code to output in that format and read in from that format. Note that this will break if the name contains a quote.

Comment: can you please give me an example of how to store the data into the file. thank you

Comment: Do you know how to visit each entry in a map? Do you know how to open a file and write to it? It's hard to know what help you need.

Comment: Even if the map should have the string as key there is no reason for the string to be first in the line. If you place the int first you can skip quoting as everything from comma to NL will be the string. When reading it just take the second value as key and not the first

Answer (score -1):

You need to improve your code. Add getters and setters to your student class because now there is no way to write to the map inside the class. For example add a method that let's you push your student info into private map member.

Then I recommend to learn about boost serialization:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

If you want a simpler way then learn about std::fstream library.

Comment: we didn't learn anything about boost serialization yet. I don't think my instructor would expect me to use that. Thank you for your reply.